# how to split two columns finding a string value from a CSV in python using re.split

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to look at other examples and questions but cannot figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

I am trying to locate a common word "for" or "fits" in a cell and then split everything after into separate columns.

Data Example:

```
Col 1     Col 2                                    Col 3
Add       Carpart for Make Model Variation 1 2 3   1000
Add       Carpart for Make Model Variation 111     1000
Add       Carpart for Make Model Variation         1000
Add       Carpart fits Make Model Variation        1000
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
Col 1     Col 2         Col 3   Col 4  Col 5            Col 6
Add       Carpart for   Make    Model  Variation 1 2 3  1000
Add       Carpart for   Make    Model  Variation 1 1 1  1000
Add       Carpart for   Make    Model  Variation        1000
Add       Carpart fits  Make    Model  Variation        1000
```

Here is as far as I have gotten but I keep getting errors for int object is not subscriptable.

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

rowCounter = 0

fileinString = 'input.csv'
fileoutString = 'output/output.csv'

with open(fileinString, "r", newline="") as inFile, open(fileoutString, "w", newline="") as outFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    readerdf = pd.DataFrame(reader)
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for row in readerdf:

        row[2].str.split(pat='.*for', expand=True)

    writer.writerow(row)
        rowCounter += 1
        screenOutput = "COMPLETED ROW: {}".format(rowCounter)
        print(screenOutput)
    else:
        print("FINISHED")
```

Comment: what your code is giving output?

Comment: you can't iterate over dataframes like that use df.iloc instead

Comment: To iterate rows of a dataframe, use `for row in df.iterrows()`

Comment: the numbers in col 5, do they get separated too?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is well behaved like the example you shown,you could split the second column into the first 4 spaces and concatenate the dataframe as needed.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

fileinString = 'input.csv'
fileoutString = 'output.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(fileinString)
print(df)

# split the first 4 spaces
df1 = df["Col 2"].str.split(pat="\s", n=4, expand=True)

# if you don't need the {for|fits} comment this line
df1[0] = df1[[0, 1]].astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1)

df1 = df1.drop(columns=[1])

df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0], df1, df.iloc[:,-1]], axis=1)

# readjust column names
df.columns = ["Col {}".format(i+1) for i in range(df.shape[1])]
print(df)

df.to_csv(fileoutString, index=False)
```

Output from **df**

```
  Col 1         Col 2 Col 3  Col 4            Col 5  Col 6
0   Add   Carpart for  Make  Model  Variation 1 2 3   1000
1   Add   Carpart for  Make  Model    Variation 111   1000
2   Add   Carpart for  Make  Model        Variation   1000
3   Add  Carpart fits  Make  Model        Variation   1000
```