# Python CSV Split columns with multiple patterns and new column titles and saving to new CSV file Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Data Example:

```
Col 1     Col 2                                    Col 3
Add       Carpart for Make Model Variation 1 2 3   1000
Add       Carpart for Make Model Variation 111     1000
Add       Carpart for Make Model Variation         1000
Add       Carpart fits Make Model Variation        1000
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
Col 1     Col 2         Col 3   Col 4  Col 5            Col 6
Add       Carpart for   Make    Model  Variation 1 2 3  1000
Add       Carpart for   Make    Model  Variation 111    1000
Add       Carpart for   Make    Model  Variation        1000
Add       Carpart fits  Make    Model  Variation        1000
```

```
import pandas as pd

fileinString = 'input.csv'
fileoutString = 'output.csv'

#Splits the product title by "For"
outputdf = reader['*Title'].str.split("for{1}", expand=True)

outputdf.to_csv(fileoutString)
print("DONE")
```

So my split works but i cannot work out how to do the following:

1. Split the data further into `4` columns in total like in the data example I am trying to achieve.
2. Name the Column output titles?
3. combine the rest of the spreadsheet.

really struggling and would appreciate any help.

Current Output:

```
    0        1
0   Carpart  Make Model Variation 1 2 3
1   Carpart  Make Model Variation 111
2   Carpart  Make Model Variation
3   Carpart  Make Model Variation
4   Carpart  Make Model Variation
5   Carpart  Make Model Variation
6   Carpart  Make Model Variation
7   Carpart  Make Model Variation
```

Comment: looks very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054007/how-to-split-two-columns-finding-a-string-value-from-a-csv-in-python-using-re-sp).

Comment: thanks for helping ;/ i used the data from this question and modelled how I handle the data from this question is there a problem I still need help?

Comment: what output are you getting

Comment: no problem at all. the similarity was just obvious. for col 5, what is the logic? do the numbers stay attached to Model Variation, or do they get their own columns? if they stick to model variation, why does 111 suddenly become 1 1 1? y is it spaced?

Comment: I think you simply need a regex pattern with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).